# Ошибка при работе с указателями C

Tags: c, указатели

При вызове данной функции получаю следующую ошибку: "Ошибка сегментирования (сделан дамп памяти)"

Вызов функции из программы:

```
point *tmp;
    tmp = delete_cell(my_space,size, small);
```

Функция:

```
point* delete_cell(point* my_space, int size, int index){
    point* new_space; 
    new_space = (point*)malloc(size-1 * sizeof(point));

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        if(i != index){
            new_space[i] = my_space[i];
        }
    }

    return new_space;  
}
```

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка сегментирования связана с обращением к памяти, которая не принадлежит вашей программе. Скорее всего, у вас ошибка в вызове функции `malloc`.

```
new_space = (point*)malloc(size-1 * sizeof(point));
```

Поскольку сначала выполняется умножение, а потом вычитание, ваш код превращается в такой:

```
new_space = (point*)malloc(size - sizeof(point));
```

Напишите так:

```
new_space = (point*)malloc((size - 1) * sizeof(point));
```

Как я понимаю, вы пытаетесь все элементы существующего массива, кроме одного, перенести в новый. И как только вы доходите до того самого элемента, вы его пропускаете, и в новом массиве на месте удаляемого элемента у вас будет мусор. А в конце цикла вы вылезете на 1 элемент за пределы массива `new_space`.

Comment: там есть ещё ошибки, даже если исправить эту. Более того, там даже алгоритм удаления реализован не совсем правильно.

Comment: @KoVadim, да, нашёл.

Comment: Спасибо за замечания, исправил все ошибки и алгоритм, все работает, благодарю за помощь. - @maestro

Comment: Спасибо, исправил алгоритм @KoVadim